# shared workflows in oozie

Tags: oozie, hue

I need to create a oozie workflow on hue oozie dashboard to be shared across multiple users. However, I donot see the 'is shared' checkbox while creating a workflow in hue CDH 5.2.0 and the workflow gets created as 'personal' thus visible to the owner only. Has the way of creating a shared workflow changed in hue? If so, how do we accomplish that?

Any tips are appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Hue 3 / C5, this happens on the /home page. You can click on the top left Home icon and then select the workflow in its 'Sharing' column to share it with other users.

This will be simplified in Hue 4!